# How do i change progress bar style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to change the default style of progress bar in html, basically i need to change a gradient color to progress bar and increase height and width

```css
#progressBar {
  background-color: #bd4f6c !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #bd4f6c 0%, #d7816a 74%) !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload_form" action="final.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="show_pro();">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress> <span id="status"> 
          </span>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing height, width, and color property in css?

Answer (score 4):

Try this using `background-image`. More details in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)

```css
progress,
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
}

progress,
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-image: #C02425;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F0CB35, #C02425);
}
```

```html
<div>
  0% progress
  <progress id="progressBar1" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
</div>
<div>
  10% progress
  <progress id="progressBar2" value="10" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please give a answer for change color while uploading level

Comment: doesn't change, still i need some solution

Comment: is `progressBar2` the one you are after?

Comment: can you explain a bit more mate, what do you mean by `uploading level` ?

Comment: i have a progress bar for file uploading,when i choose a file, after progress bar appear on the screen and track the uploading level marking blue color filling on progress bar,but i want to apply red to green linear gradient for uploading level.

Comment: how can you show your progress with a gradient? like if its `50%` would it spread within the progress bar?

Comment: i dont see any green in that, do you mean to say the blue progres?

Comment: if you visit the link,normally progress bar loading color be a blue,but i want it like linear greadient color

Answer (score 0):

```css
   
progress[value] {
  background-color: #fff;
}
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #bd4f6c 0%, #d7816a 74%) !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="upload_form" action="final.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" onchange="show_pro();">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress> <span id="status"> 
          </span>
  <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="sub">
</form>
```